# Is it possible to organize template files?

Tags: 7, theming, installation, configuration

As I've gotten more familiar with Drupal, I've been utilizing template files more and more. However, the naming conventions for template files make them difficult to organize. Is it possible to organize template files into different directories within the primary templates directory? I'm using Drupal 7.

If it isn't possible, are there alternative methods to organize template files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to organize template files into different directories within the primary templates directory?

Yes, absolutely. Drupal will recursively search the root and every subfolder in your theme for .tpl.php files.

Stick them in whatever structure suits you, Drupal will find them.